# How to insert and bind pictures in my CRUD form with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, crud

I'm working with Tkinter and I have a **CRUD** form to isert information to my SQLite database as well display them in another treeview frame, it works pretty good, but I was thinking about to isert an **'upload picture' button** and a small frame for the picture near my **CRUD options**, I have no idea how to do it, in fact that picture must be binded to my **ID code entry**, in order to work also with my **CRUD buttons**, and have different pictures for different ID numbers. Thanks guys

UPDATE:
My CRUD code is long, basically I've got this scheme:

```
frame_registres = Frame(top, width=840, height=460)
frame_registres.place(x=350, y=220)

lbl_idcard = Label(frame_registres, text='ID card', font='arial 13 bold', bg='black', fg='gray')
lbl_idcard.place(x=60, y=116)

myid = StringVar()

idcard_entry = Entry(frame_registros, font='arial 12', justify='center', relief='sunken', bd=3, textvariable=myid)
idcard_entry.place(x=130, y=108, width='160', height='30')

btn_get = Button(frame_registros)
btn_add = Button(frame_registros)
btn_update = Button(frame_registros)
btn_delete = Button(frame_registros)

  def get():
  
  def add():
  
  def update():

  def delete():
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3


top = Tk()
top.configure(width='444', heigh='400')

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def enterdata():
    id = 'hello'
    photo = convert_pic()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO test (id, photo) VALUES (?, ?)', (id, photo))
    conn.commit()

def convert_pic():
    filename = 'images/image6.jpg'
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        photo = file.read()
    return photo


btn = Button(top, text='save photo', command=enterdata())
btn.place(x='100', y='111')


mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Have you heard of `blob`?

Comment: @TheLizzard hey buddy, I've updated some code to give an idea (I tried to simplify because it has many lines)

Comment: @CoolCloud I haven't heard about that, I read I can upload the images to my folder then insert the path into my SQLite database, I'm not sure how to do it, actually every Idcard number has to be binded to an image if it exist in my folder.

Comment: You can insert entire image into the database and call it out whenever you want, just search for blob sqlite.

Comment: @CoolCloud Hey mate, untill now I was trying to get what you said, but I could't, Could you give me a signal?, I just reached to upload an image to display in a **Frame** and also tried displaying that photo in an **Entry**  using **upload button** in order to give a StringVar to my textvariable and use in my **Entry**, But when I want to use my **register button** or any other , it just store all my CRUD entries except the entry with my photo.

Comment: @CoolCloud Now I can store a blob data into my database, But I don't now how to make it works with my CRUD form, by the way I've got an 'UPDATED 2' for my question. thanks

Comment: The datatype of the column `photo` should be `BLOB`.

Comment: @CoolCloud,  Yes I gave that option to my photo column, I can store pictures in my database,  But I can't make it work with my CRUD form, how and where to display a photo in my CRUD form?,  ( in a label? or frame,  or an entry?) ,  my other CRUD entries have a *texvalue* for example for my ID entry that **textvalue** is **myid = StringVar() **, so I can use **myid.get()** with my CRUD buttons (create, update, delete,..)

Comment: Label is usually where images are shown.

Comment: @CoolCloud Hey mate, I've been trying but I'm stucked, I've posted a new question, hope you can guide me. Thanks